# Templating in Django

Tags: django, jinja2

I am new to Django development and stuck over a issue. From `views.py` I am sending one list

```
return render(request, 'InsertPage/About.html' , {'list1': list1})
```

and want to able to perform operations on this list in the html page. Eg list contains 6 items, 3 index per product. I wish to create operations like get the length of the list divide it by 3 and the quotient would be the number of products. And using the same variable (no of products) I was planning to make a for loop to create bootstrap cols and dynamically load the data to the html page. 
here is the html code

```
{% for i in list1 %}
     <h1> {{ k }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Would really appreciate the help, also open for suggestions if there is a better way to achieve what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use a more convenient data structure, for example a list of dictionaries where each dictionary represents an item (product) with the properties of each item at each iteration of the list.

For example, the list of two items:

```
list1 = [{
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}, {
  "brand": "Mercury",
  "model": "Cougar",
  "year": 1969
}]
```

Then you can access the properties in your template:

```
{% for item in list1 %}    
 <h1> {{ item.brand }} </h1>
 {{ item.model}}
{% endfor %}
```